# Extraer un patrón de una cadena de string en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

tengo que sacar de una cadena de string solo los códigos que sean así:

```
{i:0;s:19:"1813-EB89-AF94-E911";i:1;s:19:"EC1E-456C-3141-1886";}a:6:{i:0;s:19:"D4EB-3408-F2CF-F4ED";i:1;s:19:"F0D3-AE1C-24D9-96FC";i:2;s:19:"01EC-B252-36EA-445E";
```

De aquí debería extraer:

```
1813-EB89-AF94-E911, EC1E-456C-3141-1886, etc.
```

Siempre son 12 caracteres divididos en 4 por guiones. He intentado con varias funciones pero nada, no sé si sería mejor crear un patrón o hay alguna manera de hacer un `implode` que permita coger los valores comprendidos entre `:"` y `";`

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Eso no es una cadena de string, sino datos serializados, que además has puesto de forma incompleta en la pregunta y no puedo darte bien la respuesta, para que usando [unserialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.unserialize.php) sobre ellos puedas recuperar sus valores sin tener que usar expresiones regulares sobre esa supuesta cadena.

Answer (score 1):

Eso no es una cadena de string, sino [datos serializados en PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_serialization_format), que además has puesto de forma incompleta en la pregunta y no puedo darte bien la respuesta.

Suponiendo que tuvieras estos datos:

> a:6:{i:0;s:19:"D4EB-3408-F2CF-F4ED";i:1;s:19:"F0D3-AE1C-24D9-96FC";i:2;s:19:"01EC-B252-36EA-445E";i:3;s:19:"01EC-B252-36EA-445E";i:4;s:19:"01EC-B252-36EA-445E";i:5;s:19:"01EC-B252-36EA-445E";}

podrias pasarles la función [unserialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.unserialize.php) sobre ellos para recuperar sus valores sin tener que usar expresiones regulares sobre esa supuesta cadena, de esta forma:

```
$datos_serializados = 'a:6:{i:0;s:19:"D4EB-3408-F2CF-F4ED";i:1;s:19:"F0D3-AE1C-24D9-96FC";i:2;s:19:"01EC-B252-36EA-445E";i:3;s:19:"01EC-B252-36EA-445E";i:4;s:19:"01EC-B252-36EA-445E";i:5;s:19:"01EC-B252-36EA-445E";}';
$array_datos = unserialize($cadena);
print_r($array_datos);
```

Lo que te devolveria un array para su posterior tratamiento:

```
Array
(
    [0] => D4EB-3408-F2CF-F4ED
    [1] => F0D3-AE1C-24D9-96FC
    [2] => 01EC-B252-36EA-445E
    [3] => 01EC-B252-36EA-445E
    [4] => 01EC-B252-36EA-445E
    [5] => 01EC-B252-36EA-445E
)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto me resolvía el problema principal pero me daba un nuevo problema: solo me cogía el primer parámetro que encontraba entre corchetes, y a veces la consulta me devuelve varios parámetros entre corchetes.

Comment: Pues revisa la consulta, no se de donde sacas esos datos o si los concatenas sin querer y por eso después no puedes deserializarlos con unserialize() correctamente.

Comment: O muéstrame un ejemplo completo de lo que dices ahora, poniéndolo en la pregunta, que no esté cortado como el de la pregunta, para que pueda jugar con el. Seguramente con un explode primero lo podría solucionar, pero necesito ver exactamente que tienes y no un cacho solo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar una expresión regular para extraer esos datos. Aclaro no soy muy experto creando regex, pero este funciona bien:

```php
preg_match_all('/[\w]{4}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{4}-[\w]{4}/', $la_cadena, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Míralo funcionando [Aquí](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/H5j#tab-preg-match-all)

Comment: MIL GRACIAS!! esto era justo lo que buscaba